# Lenovo Y580 battery - Panasonic NCR18650b MH12210

Tags: batteries, laptop

I am new to the group, so thank you for this great community. I am a student and "DIYer" and like to repair simple electronics.

Anyway, so here is my situation:
Want to repair my laptop battery as there are no more spare being built (Thank you Lenovo) and cracking open the cover of my pack to identify the cells I have these inside: Panasonic NCR18650b MH12210.

Now according to may pack label, I have 10.8 v 72WH 6700 mah, meaning each cell around 1116.6 mah. But looking online the cell is rated at 3200 - 3400 mah!!

Could someone please let me know if there are variation to this cell? meaning there is 1100 mah version of it? I could not find it. Or other cells I can use instead.

I have attached some images of the battery pack and cells.

Any help / suggestion would be appreciated

Cheers

[image: Battery pavk]
[image: Panasonic NCR18650b MH12210]

Answer (score 2):

Your battery has 6 cells in a series/parallel combination something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBZZwA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each cell is 3350mAh, so 2 in parallel add up to 6700mAh.
3 pairs in series then give you 10.8V.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply and explanation. That's great. So is it possible to use higher mah battery? Am I right to assume W=VI, so more ah more power?

Comment: There are no higher mah batteries, outside of the F1L or GA cells (and they're more expensive for a trivial gain).

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. Do you have any tips or suggestions on replacing them?

Answer (score 0):

Buy a replacement , keep cool and never drain  to zero charge for long periods.  Expect less lifetime.

http://www.battdepot.com/ca/opn/notebook+battery/lenovo/l11p6r01/lln230.aspx

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the non OEM packs won't work for ideapads, it recognize the PCB and won't accept them.
https://www.google.fr/search?[link]q=lenovo+ideapd+non+oem+battery&rlz=1C1KMOH_enMY649MY650&oq=lenovo+ideapd+non+oem+battery&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6841j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8[link]

Comment: You can still get genuine battery packs online but is it worth it?  Or you can buy Panasonic cells and hope a repair works

Comment: No, I have contacted many Lenovo and IBM distributors. Many emails and forums posts later, no luck. The only packs you can get are 4400 mah and around 60-80 $ without shipping. So already bought the cells, reading online how to replace them. Not an easy task!

Comment: Does the charger operate mobile without battery? It should.

Comment: Yes, it does. No issues with the charger, and even though the capacity of the cells has dropped to 2400 mah it does not shut down suddenly and it charges up normally.